# OpenMP - using parallel for calling function inside in a loop, working with Mat object

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have a text (about `136.000` characters), and I would like to write them in the a picture. My text stores in the `vector`, it means that I can use loop `for` for changing a `low bit` of a pixel.

This is function changes a `last bit`:

```
int changeLastChar(int value, int newEnd) {
    // change last decimal of an integer
    if (newEnd > 9) return 1;
    value /= 10;
    value *= 10;
    value += newEnd;
    return value;
}
```

This one is writting inside a picture:

```
void writeTextToImage3(Mat& image, std::vector<char> message, int count) {
    // write text to pixels by changing the last decimal in every RGB value
    int ascii;
    int row;
    int col;


#pragma omp parallel 
    {
        #pragma omp for
        for (int i = 0; i < message.size(); i++)
        {

            row = count/ image.cols;
            col = count % image.cols;

            ascii = message[i];
            count++;


            image.at<Vec3b>(row, col)[0] = changeLastChar(image.at<Vec3b>(row, col)[0], ascii % 10);    // blue

            ascii /= 10;
            image.at<Vec3b>(row, col)[1] = changeLastChar(image.at<Vec3b>(row, col)[1], ascii % 10);    // green

            ascii /= 10;
            image.at<Vec3b>(row, col)[2] = changeLastChar(image.at<Vec3b>(row, col)[2], ascii % 10);    // red                                                                                                                                                          
        }

    }
}
```

I can give some results, that if I use the function `without OpenMP`, it takes: `0.29..`.

`With OpenMP` using `#pragma omp for`: `0.26..`

`With OpenMP` using `#pragma omp parallel for`: `0.17..`

I know the difference between `for` and `parallel for`, that if I use just `for` , I have only one main thread, NOT a group.

**But as for my problem:** I need an exact `row` and `col` number for every `ascii`. I see the diffirence of taking time, and I really like to see `0.17..`. But.. if I understand clearly, when I use `parallel for`: it creates several threads and every part of iterations goes for every thread of several ones. Okay. 
But I can't understand, why does it work only for `the first iteration` and others can't go on changing bits?

**My thoughts are that:** When some part (not first, some..) is working , It counts a variable`cout++`, which calculates `row and col`. Sure, it starts to count from `0` , but I need to count `THE FIRST THREAD` from `0` , not some part. 
That's why if I don't use `parallel` , it goes in the correct order because it has one main thread.

Can you help? Can I use `parallel for` in a correct way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `count` is shared among all the threads, you get a race condition since it is written to in each loop.  You also get race conditions on your local variables, which should be declared within the loop rather than outside of it (so that each thread will have its own copy).

You already have `i` that increments when `count` does, so you can use that.  Don't modify `count`, change your `row` and `col` calculation to use `count` with `i`:

```
int row = (count + i) / image.cols;
int col = (count + i) % image.cols;
int ascii = message[i];
```

You can also just call `image.at<Vec3b>(row, col)` once, store that result in a variable, and use that:

```
auto &v = image.at<Vec3b>(row, col);

v[0] = changeLastChar(v[0], ascii % 10);
// etc.
```

Comment: Yes, that was what I was looking for! Thank you so much, I won that time. It goes about `0.12..`. Thank you!